# Pressable onPress not working on Android but fine on iOS

Tags: css, react-native

Can't figure this out. Read other problems like this but could not fix it. When I click onPress in my Android simulator the console log won't work but on iOS works perfectly.
I tried to fix it by removing the position 'absolute' in the first View but my app completely disappears in the background(I see white everywhere and only the Modal is visible).

**modal.js:**

```
{
    props.isModalLoadingVisible &&
    <View style={{
        width: '100%', height: '100%', position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, zIndex: 99999999999, elevation: 99999999999
    }}>
        <Image style={styleModalLoading.backgroundModal} source={backgroundGrayOpacity} />
        <View style={styleModalLoading.centeredView}>
            <View style={styleModalLoading.modalView}>
                <View style={styleModalLoading.logoContainer}>
                    <Image style={styleModalLoading.logo} source={Logo} />
                    <Text style={styleModalLoading.text}>LOADING...</Text>
                </View>
                {
                    props.isBtnCancelVisible &&
                    <Pressable onPress={() => {props.closeModalLoading; console.log("onPress works")}} style={styleModalLoading.btnCancel}>
                        <Text style={styleModalLoading.btnCancelTxt}>CANCEL</Text>
                    </Pressable>
                }
            </View>
        </View>
    </View>
}
```

**style.js:**

```
export const styleModalLoading = StyleSheet.create({
    backgroundModal: {
        position: 'absolute', 
        height: '100%', 
        width: '100%'
    },
    centeredView: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    modalView: {
        margin: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 20,
        padding: 35,
        alignItems: 'center',
        shadowColor: '#000',
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 2,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 4,
        elevation: 5,
        width: '94%',
    },   
    logoContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        marginTop: 14,
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    text: {
        color: '#aaa',
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 8,
    },
    btnCancel: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: 40,
        width: 120,
        borderRadius: 10,
        elevation: 3,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderColor: '#96c94f',
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginTop: 30,
    },
    btnCancelTxt: {
        color: '#96c94f',
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
});
```

Maybe some sharp css mind can figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: Just two guesses:
1. Ensure that pressable were not obscured by another view with element inspector
2. Add property `flex:0` to  btnCancel

Comment: add minimum code to demonstrate your issue,  using your above code I cannot recreate the issue